# Passing data from servlet to another servlet using RequestDispatcher

Tags: servlets, requestdispatcher

I am trying to pass data from one servlet to another using the RequestDispatcher. This is my code for the Dispatcher.

```
String address;

address = "/Java Resources/src/coreservlets/MapOut.java";

RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
  request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

When I try to run it, it gives me an error saying the path is unavailable. Do I have to include something for the dispatcher to send to another servlet?

Answer (score 12):

You just need to pass `servlet-mapping` 's `url-pattern` in the `getRequestDispatcher`.

Let say your servlet mapping is "myMap" for the "MapOut" Servlet in the `web.xml`.Then it should be

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/myMap");
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

`doGet()` of forwarded Servlet will be called.

Example: web.xml

```
      <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <servlet-name>MapOut</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>coreservlets.MapOut</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MapOut</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myMap</url-pattern> <!-- You can change this-->
      </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I am still  a bit confused, what do you mean by servlet mapping.

Comment: RequestDispatcher rd;
 rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/MapOut");
 rd.forward(request, response);  

this is what i have on the servlet that I want the attributes created in to be forwarded to "\MapOut" ... do I have to make a request in the MapOut class?

Comment: Can we have a servlet without a mapping?

Comment: @HardikMishra I have a small question. Don't we need request.setAttribute() method by setting attribute to forward? And why don't we use that?

Comment: @pippilongstocking : You can use that but here the question was about forwarding not on setting attributes

Answer (score 1):

You can directly write your name of the servlet in `request.getRequestDispatcher("your servlet name");` it will fetch the path according to the web.xml configuration.

```
RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("MyServletName");
rd.forward(request,response);
```

Comment: It is  not working. plz let me in which  version it is  working..I am using servlet 2.4

Comment: @saurabh yes. it's working in servlet version 2.4,
please check the name of servlet and path.

Comment: This done via `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getNamedDispatcher(String)`. `request.getRequestDispatcher` works only for paths