# How to correctly include output from one servlet to another?

Tags: servlets

The problem is that the servlet can't include response from another one. Well, I have one servlet called "Query" which has such block:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlets/counter");
    if (dispatcher != null) {
        out.println("<br>Number of visits: ");
        request.setAttribute(Counter.ATTRIBUTE, Query.class.getName());
        dispatcher.include(request, response);
    }
    out.println("</body>");
```

It is designed to include another servlet's response into the current servlet. Then, I have the other servlet called "Counter" which has this line:

```
if (counterName == null) counterName = (String)request.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE);
```

So, when I run "Query" there is no output from "Counter". You can review the full project from [this repository](https://github.com/ereminmax/MyFirstServlets) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Mistake was at the .getRequestDispatcher method. The parameter has to contain not servlet's class location, but it's mapping. Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457336/passing-data-from-servlet-to-another-servlet-using-requestdispatcher)